# Create nginx docker image from npm web app with GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, nginx, npm, github-actions

I'm trying to create a docker image using GitHub Actions from a static web application built with npm. However, while running the dockerfile, the /dist folder is not copied into the image as expected.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And this is the action:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*

jobs:
  build-homolog:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Build
        env:
          NODE_ENV: homolog
        run: npm install; npm run build; docker build -t my-image:1.0.0 .
```

The result is a working nginx but without content, it just shows its default page. When I run the npm build and the docker build locally on my machine, it works as expected. I think there is a problem with the directory structure on the GitHub Actions machine, but I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: I would recomend to do a multi-stage build with the node version docker image and then copy that the nginx container

Comment: Well, don't ask me why, but simply changing from nginx to apache did the trick. The problem was not with GitHub Actions at all.